# What happens at $V=Nb$ in the Van der Waals equation (i.e. becomes divergent)?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, collision, ideal-gas, gas

The VdW equation:
$$\left(P+a\left(\frac{N^2}{V^2}\right) \right)\left(V-Nb\right)=Nk_BT$$

when the intermolecular forces are zero $a=0$, so $P=\frac{Nk_BT}{V-Nb}$ which diverges at $V=Nb$ for fixed temperature.

I'm simulating some hard sphere collisions, with $r_{sphere}=0.5, R_{contianer}=10 $. From some curvefit I got $b \approx 2.2$, so when $N>143$ (or less than 50% of the volume/area),the VdW equation breaks down.

Does that imply a different law holds when the number of particles becomes large? But isn't $b \propto r^3$ anyway, so it should account  for the case when the number of particles are large?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $b$ is the volume of a molecule, and $Nb$ is the volume occupied by all the molecules in the gas. So $V\rightarrow Nb$ corresponds to squeezing the gas to a point where the molecules cannot move anymore. The fact that something diverges in this limit is a good indication that, perhaps, the underlying theory (i.e., the van der Waals equation) does not apply there.